# How to show only the id of one table and not to duplicate with other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 6 tables and 3 of them is what I need to show in my table and the other 3 is what I needed to hide in the same table.

Report:

```
id    name    branch    comp_id    start_date    end_date
100    A        001       011      2022-08-14    2022-08-14
200    B        002       012      2022-08-14    2022-08-14
```

Report Details:

```
id    product_id    product_code   price   deliveries
100    01           11             20.00    10
100    01           11             20.00    10
200    01           11             20.00    20
200    02           12             25.00    20
```

Products:

```
id    code   name     
01     11      Prod 1
02     12      Prod 2
```

Product Details:

```
id    code   name     Desc
01     11    Prod 1   Desc 1
02     12    Prod 2   Desc 2
```

Branches:

```
id    code   name     
001    021    Branch 1
002    022    Branch 2
```

Companies:

```
id    name        branch
011   Company 1   021
012   Company 2   022
```

I want the output to be like this:

id: will come from reports  table
branch_name: will come from branches table using the branch in report table
company_name: will come company using the comp_id in report table
product_name: will come from products table using product_id in report details table
description: will come from product_details table using product_code in report details table 
start_date: will come from report table
end_date: will come from report table

```
id    branch_name    company_name    product_name    description    start_date    end_date
100    branch 1        Company 1     Prod 1          Desc 1         2022-08-14    2022-08-14
200    branch 2        Company 2     Prod 1          Desc 1         2022-08-14    2022-08-14
200    branch 2        Company 2     Prod 2          Desc 2         2022-08-14    2022-08-14
```

I have this sql and it all shows the id in report details table:

```
SELECT *, `acc`.`name` AS `cname`, `out`.`name` AS `outname`, `pro`.`name` AS `pname`, `prod`.`name` AS `sname` 
FROM `report` AS `rep` 
JOIN `companies` AS `acc` ON `rep`.`account_id`=`acc`.`code` 
JOIN `branches` AS `out` ON `rep`.`outlet_id`=`out`.`code`
JOIN `report_details` AS `red` ON `rep`.`report_id`=`red`.`report_id`
JOIN `products` AS `pro` ON `red`.`product_id`=`pro`.`id`
JOIN `product_details` AS `prod` ON `red`.`sku_id`=`prod`.`id`
```

Comment: Maybe use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to post an example, so both you and others can experiment with the existing schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT R.id, B.name AS branch_name, C.name AS company_name, PD.product_name AS product_name, PD.Desc AS description, R.start_date
FROM Report R
LEFT JOIN report_details RD ON R.id = R.id
LEFT JOIN products P ON RD.product_id = P.id
LEFT JOIN product_details PD ON PD.product_id = PD.id
LEFT JOIN branches B ON R.branch = B.id
LEFT JOIN companies C ON R.comp_id = C.id
GROUP BY R.id, B.name, C.name, PD.product_name, PD.Desc, R.start_date
```